this is my query below and i am getting error - " Expecting closing quote. The error is caused by «')\n '»."
Query:
wiql_query = {
        "query": f"""SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.Tags]
                     FROM WorkItems
                     WHERE [System.TeamProject] = '{project_name}'
                     AND [System.Title] = '{str(title_item)}'
                     AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Removed', 'Closed')
                     AND [System.BoardColumn] NOT IN ('Recycle Bin')
                     """,
    }

I was trying to send request using above query but observing error as specified in title

I can reproduce similar error when the work item title contains special characters, which could not have closing quote, or incorrect quote used.

You can change the work item title to remove the characters, the script works then.

The script sample:
from azure.devops.connection import Connection
from msrest.authentication import BasicAuthentication
from azure.devops.v7_1.work_item_tracking.models import Wiql

# Your personal access token and organization URL
token = "PAT"
organization_url = "https://dev.azure.com/orgname"

# Create a connection to the org
credentials = BasicAuthentication('', token)
connection = Connection(base_url=organization_url, creds=credentials)

# Get a client (the "work_item_tracking" client provides functions to work with queries)
wit_client = connection.clients.get_work_item_tracking_client()

wiql_query = {
        "query": f"""SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.Tags]
                     FROM WorkItems
                     WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'ASP_NET'
                     AND [System.Title] = 'Bug3 test title.'
                     AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Removed', 'Closed')
                     AND [System.BoardColumn] NOT IN ('Recycle Bin')
                     """,
    }
    
    
# Run the query
wiql_results = wit_client.query_by_wiql(wiql_query).work_items

# If the query returned results, print the work item IDs
if wiql_results:
    for work_item in wiql_results:
        print(work_item.id)


Or you can change the clauses in the wiql, checking with [System.Id] instead of [System.Title].
wiql_query = {
        "query": f"""SELECT [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.Tags]
                     FROM WorkItems
                     WHERE [System.TeamProject] = 'ASP_NET'
                     AND [System.Id] = '277'
                     AND [System.State] NOT IN ('Deleted', 'Removed', 'Closed')
                     AND [System.BoardColumn] NOT IN ('Recycle Bin')
                     """,
    }

